# After Update to 2.2.1 'href' is not allowed

Tags: error, magento-2.2.1

After I updated magento with composer to 2.2.1 in frontend shows following error:

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'link', attribute 'href': The attribute 'href' is not allowed.
>   Line: 33

How can I fix this? I can't locate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to checkout in your all module or theme level layout files to check any css are assigned with href="csspath".**

This issue will come because of  tag with href is assigned in Magento 2.2.* you need to replace href with src tag to sort out the issue.

**Replace**

```
<link href="link to css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

**with src**

```
<link src="link to css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the layout xml files, '**src**' is not an HTML attribute for link elements, but it is for the layout xml files.

Earlier versions of magento did not properly validate the xml, and thus an error such as using '**href**' when you are supposed to use '**src**' did not throw an error. Apparently this was fixed in 2.2.0, but there are still errors in the validation code that are being worked on, see these commits for example:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/be572a29dd96c1d3693461aff96f028fe7628d73

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/4d79191e6cf75dfde33a6b38a12d9d06c1e1748c